# Summing infinite series that converge only for some parameter values

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, summation

The input

```
Sum[d^t,{t,0,Infinity}]
```

produces output

```
1/(1-d)
```

which is correct for $|d|<1$. But for $|d|\geq1$ the sum does not converge so the output is wrong.

Why does *Mathematica* not produce any warning or indication that this is the case?

For more complicated cases where the non-convergence might not be obvious upon cursory inspection, is there a way for *Mathematica* to output both a sum and a condition for convergence?

Comment: You can check first with [`SumConvergence`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SumConvergence.html), `SumConvergence[d^t, t]` gives `Abs[d] < 1`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Sum[d^t, {t, 0, Infinity}, GenerateConditions -> True]
(*

ConditionalExpression[1/(1 - d), Abs[d] < 1]

*)
```