# surprising behavior of `Sum`

Tags: symbolic, summation

Compare the following.  (The option specified is the default value; just to be explicit.)

```
Sum[b^n, {n, 0, ∞}, VerifyConvergence -> True]  (* 1/(1-b) *)
Sum[2^n, {n, 0, ∞}, VerifyConvergence -> True]  (* failure to converge *)
```

Is this difference behavior deducible from the documentation?  Should the first result be considered a bug, or just a feature that counts on user discretion?

Comment: $\sum^\infty_{i=1}{i^n}|i<1$ is a well known sum, this is more a basic maths question.

Comment: This issue comes up a lot: [(13275)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/13275/121),
[(46453)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/46453/121),
[(83957)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/83957/121),
[(91450)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/91450/121),
[(109712)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/109712/121), etc.  We should probably have a canonical Q&A, and additionally it should be added to [(18393)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18393/121)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One option `Sum` provides is `GenerateConditions`

```
Sum[b^n, {n, 0, ∞}, GenerateConditions -> True]
Sum[2^n, {n, 0, ∞}, GenerateConditions -> True]
```

The first replies:

```
ConditionalExpression[1/(1 - b), Abs[b] < 1]
```

while the second gives the `Sum does not converge` warning.

Comment: Plus, the documentaiton has remarks such as "Use GenerateConditions to get the conditions under which the answer is true:", "Get the conditions for summability:", "Get the conditions for convergence:", etc.

Comment: @Szabolcs That's a bit useful, but what documentation are you looking at.  I'm looking here https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sum.html and here https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GenerateConditions.html  Also, please see my subsequent comment.

Comment: Bill, I might be missing your point or misunderstanding `GenerateConditions` ...  I expected the result you report, but my question is about the result when `GenerateConditions` has the default value of `False`.  The value returned is valid only for a very restricted range of `b`.  Why is that the correct thing for Mma to return in this case?  What is the principle at work?

Comment: @Alan It's the Sum page you linked to.  I agree it's not easy to find. It's among the examples.

Comment: @Alan -- I certainly can't speak for the developers intent in choosing the default options. It does go to underscore that you can't blindly trust computer algebra systems. Maybe a good motto would be "trust but verify".

Answer (score 3):

Some divergent sums can be evaluated using [`Regularization`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Regularization.html).  In this specific case, `Regularization->"Borel"` gives the result that you expected from your first `Sum`

```
Sum[2^n, {n, 0, ∞}, Regularization -> "Borel"]

(*  -1  *)
```

Your first `Sum` is

```
f1[b_] = Sum[b^n, {n, 0, ∞}]

(*  1/(1 - b)  *)
```

While the `Sum` converges only for `Abs[b] < 1`, the closed form is defined for `b != 1`

```
FunctionDomain[f1[b], b]

(*  b < 1 || b > 1  *)
```

The regularized `Sum` is

```
f2[b_] := Sum[b^n, {n, 0, ∞}, Regularization -> "Borel"]
```

As with `f1`, `f2[1]` is undefined

```
f2[1]

(*  Sum[1, {n, 0, ∞}, Regularization -> "Borel"]  *)
```

However, `f2[0]` is also undefined since `0^0` (the first term) is undefined

```
f2[0]

(*  Sum[0^n, {n, 0, ∞}, Regularization -> "Borel"]  *)
```

Demonstrating that the functions are equivalent (except for `b == 0`)

```
Plot[{f1[b], f2[b]}, {b, -3, 3},
 Exclusions -> {b == 0, b == 1},
 PlotStyle -> (AbsoluteDashing[#] & /@
    {{5, 5}, {10, 10}}),
 PlotLegends -> {f1, f2}]
```

[image]

However, `f2` is much slower

```
AbsoluteTiming[ans1 = f1 /@ Cases[Range[-3, 3, 1/20], _Rational];]

(*  {0.000225, Null}  *)

AbsoluteTiming[ans2 = f2 /@ Cases[Range[-3, 3, 1/20], _Rational];]

(*  {1.62083, Null}  *)
```

Verifying that results are identical

```
ans1 === ans2

(*  True  *)
```

Comment: Thanks, but I am not asking about regularization.  I am asking why the first case returns a result that is not generally true (and in fact is true for a narrow range of parameter values).  Since the default `Regularization` is `None`, I don't think that the possibility of regularization justifies the return value in the first case.  What is the principle at work.
I realize Mma often returns expressions that are not true for all parameter values, but usually this is a matter of ignoring singularities in order to produce a generally useful result.  This example does not fit that justification.